# Javascript Array as More Readable Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a data set like following table.

```
+------+---------+----+----+----+----+-------+----------+
| Year | Subject | A  | B  | C  | F  | Total | PassRate |
+------+---------+----+----+----+----+-------+----------+
| 2015 | Maths   | 12 | 20 | 10 |  5 |    47 |       80 |
| 2015 | Sinhala | 18 | 14 |  5 | 10 |    47 |       75 |
| 2016 | Maths   | 25 | 15 |  4 |  8 |    52 |       25 |
| 2016 | Sinhala | 20 | 12 |  2 | 18 |    52 |       60 |
+------+---------+----+----+----+----+-------+----------+
```

I want to store those data in JavaScript array. So I have following code.

```js
var firstArray = [];
firstArray.push(['Year', 'Subject', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'Total', 'PassRate']); // headers
firstArray.push([2015, 'Maths', 12, 20, 10, 5, 47, 80]); // 1st row
firstArray.push([2015, 'Sinhala', 18, 14, 5, 10, 47, 75]) // 2nd row
console.log(firstArray);
```

If I need to read how many **"B"**,s in Maths for 2015, I need to run `firstArray[1][3]`.

That is not readable. I mean it is hard to find what it means `firstArray[1][3]`.

So is there way to build my array more readable way like `firstArray[2015]['maths']` if I want to read how many **"B"**,s in Maths for 2015

Comment: You need an array of objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you want an object indexed by year, containing objects indexed by subject:

```js
const years = {
  '2015': {
    Maths: {
      A: 12, B: 20, C: 10, F: 5, Total: 47, PassRate: 80
    },
    Sinhala: {
      A: 18, B: 14, C: 5, F: 10, Total: 47, PassRate: 75
    },
  },
  '2016': {
    // ...
  }
}
console.log(years['2015'].Maths);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your purpose is correct, readability of code is very important.

It's not easy and there is no right path to follow, but I try to give you some hints on how to change your code.

First point: naming.

This is very hard, and often even experienced developer need to rename variables as they can't get the proper name at the first time.

Your variable is *firstArray* and this of course have low meaning and you can just say it is an array and it is the first...

Nothing about what the array is containing.

A better name could be *studentsScoreByYear*.

The improvement of this name is that it try to address the meaning of the content.

Then the index ad *magic numbers*.

Of course you need numbers to get a field from an array, and if you just use the proper integer in the code is very complicated to remember what this field is.

A way is to avoid array and use hash map, in javascript plain objects.
So you can give to each field a name.

If you can't abbandon the array for whatever reason, you can improve here too, just use constants to save the proper indexes:

```
 var MATHS = 1;
 var SCORE_OF_B = 3;

 var studentsScoreByYear= [
    ['Year', 'Subject', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'Total', 'PassRate'],
    [2015, 'Maths', 12, 20, 10, 5, 47, 80],
    [2015, 'Sinhala', 18, 14, 5, 10, 47, 75]
];

console.log(studentsScoreByYear[MATHS][SCORE_OF_B]);
```

There are other ways of course, this is just a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

A list of objects is what you want to represent your data in a readable format.

As for selecting data:

- You can filter an array by using the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on the array.
- You can change the contents or isolate a parameter with the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on the array.
- You can perform arithmetic operations with the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on the array.

```js
var data = [
    { year: 2015, subject: 'Maths', a: 12, b: 20, c: 10, f: 5, total: 47, passrate: 80 },
    { year: 2015, subject: 'Sinhala', a: 18, b: 14, c: 5, f: 10, total: 47, passrate: 75 },
    { year: 2016, subject: 'Maths', a: 25, b: 15, c: 4, f: 8, total: 52, passrate: 25 },
    { year: 2016, subject: 'Sinhala', a: 20, b: 12, c: 2, f: 18, total: 52, passrate: 60 },
];
console.log("Present All:");
console.log(data
    .map(function (row) {
    return [row.year, row.subject, row.a, row.b, row.c, row.f, row.total, row.passrate].join(", ");
})
    .join("\n"));
console.log("Count `B` in `Maths` in 2015");
console.log(data
    .filter(function (row) { return row.year === 2015 && row.subject === "Maths"; })
    .map(function (row) { return row.b; })
    .reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) { return accumulator + currentValue; }, 0));
```

Sidenote

The eagle-eyed out there has probably already spotted that the `map` and `filter` calls are redundant in the "Present All" example as i could simply have put:

`data.reduce(function (accumulator, row) {
    return accumulator + (row.year === 2015 && row.subject === "Maths" ? row.b : 0);
}, 0);`

While the above code is "smarter", i think the more verbose answer using `map` and `filter` will be of more use to anyone trying to learn JavaScript array handling and JavaScript objects.